# How to fix Fivem Qbcore error Scheduler lua

Tags: lua, scheduler, fivem

i have problem with my coding error, does anyone got this kind of problem?

```
[      script:qb-core] SCRIPT ERROR: citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:741: SCRIPT ERROR: ?:-1: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')
[      script:qb-core] > <unknown> (@oxmysql/dist/build.js:22252)
[      script:qb-core] > runMicrotasks (<anonymous>:0)
[      script:qb-core] > processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96)
[      script:qb-core]
[      script:qb-core] > TriggerCallback (@qb-core/server/functions.lua:250)
[      script:qb-core] > handler (@qb-core/server/events.lua:146)
[      script:qb-core] > <unknown> (@oxmysql/dist/build.js:22252)
[      script:qb-core] > runMicrotasks (<anonymous>:0)
[      script:qb-core] > processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96)
```

i have search internet for this problem and most of them is not working.